# Swift - Is dispatching to the main queue enough to make a var thread safe?

Tags: ios, swift

When it comes to synchronization solutions, I know there are a lot of stuff I can use in order to make a var thread safe. But my question is this:
Since the main queue is serial, is dispatching to it enough to make a var safe for async reading/writing operations?
Let's say I have an Int array:

```
var myArr: [Int] = []
```

Whenever I need to update it i use the main queue:

```
let newVal = 123

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    myArr.append(newVal)
})
```

And whenever I need to read from it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    println(myArr.count)
})
```

Will that be enough to make myArr thread safe?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to read the value asynchronously? In your code you can use `myArr.count` only inside the completion block.

Comment: Well, that was only an example, to illustrate my question. In my actual project, the array will be accessed and written to by callbacks from the JavaScriptCore, which means it has to be asynced and i need to be sure that whenever those requests arrive, they will be executed in the right order and not collide.

Comment: Perhaps you can add more concrete code to your question, in particular how the callbacks read the array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is enough. As long as you read and write from the same serial queue you are safe.